# Getting different output for same PROPS in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

My code is like below

```
props: ['applicants',],
methods : {
   formated (item) {
       console.log('first')
       console.log(Object.keys(this.applicants).length)
   },
   fetchapplicants () {
       console.log('second')
       console.log(Object.keys(this.applicants).length)
   }
},
created () {
   EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);
},
beforeMount(){
   this.fetchapplicants();
},
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

Why I am getting different output ?

Comment: Show the template. How is the property `applicants` bound? This output makes sense, if `applicants` changed.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior for your reply. Acutally I am not using `applicants` in HTML. Thanks.

Comment: How are you using, it then? What is triggering the `change` event?

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior. It is coming from another component. It is related to some checkboxes of that component. I am receiving values using that `change` event in this component. Thanks.

Comment: Look, the output depends entirely on what the other component (of which `applicants` comes from) does. You can try posting it (or building a JSFiddle demo). --- Also, maybe printing it using `console.log(this.applicants)` may give you hints on what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior.`created () {
EventBus.$on('change',this.formated)
}`

How can I replace the `change` with `onload` ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think 'onload' works that way. Maybe replacing `created () {
   EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);
},` with `mounted() { this.formated(); },` achieves what you want.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior. I need to executed this portion `EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);` at the time of loading. Thanks.

Comment: More or less, the code at `mounted()` is executed at the time of loading. So if you put `mounted() { EventBus.$on('change',this.formated); }`, then `EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);` would be executed at the time of loading.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior. Actually I need to execute `this.formated` at the time of loading along with `EventBus.$on()`. Thanks.

Comment: Then try `mounted() { this.formated(); EventBus.$on('change',this.formated); }`, then. Notice no argument `item` is being passed to `this.formated();`, though.

Comment: Looks like you mount your application on a html element that does not exist: el: '#application' but not tag `id="application"`